# Design of proportions comparison experiment (Frequentist and Bayesian)

Tags: bayesian, experiment-design, statistical-power, proportion, frequentist

I need to design an animal experiment where I test the survival proportion following administration of a vaccine and inoculation of the disease. I have 3 vaccines in the trial, the control (C), the standard (S), and the test vaccine I design (T). I am trying to conduct a power analysis to correctly choose the number of mice required. I am also interested in the Bayesian approach and trying to understand it. I use R.

From previous experiments I have the following proportion estimations:

- pC = 0.15
- pS = 0.85
- pT >= 0.45

I am testing a version of the test vaccine that I anticipate being at least equal, or better than the 0.45 survival measured before. I want to test 2 separates hypothesis:

- a)   The test vaccine provides higher protection than the control
  vaccine (pT>pC)
- b)   The test vaccine provides non-inferior (NI) protection than the
  standard vaccine given a NI margin m of 0.2, decided as a threshold
  to push the test vaccine to the next step (pS-pT<m)

### I.Frequentist approach:

To estimate the number of mice for to test a) I can use power.prop.test, but I am not sure of the procedure for the test of the NI b) assuming that the new pT would be close to pS.
I did write this code where I simulated 5000 experiments assuming binomial law for the number of survivors and using different number of animals n and possible pT and computed the power counting the number of times in the simulations the CI of the difference between Standard and Test proportions was below 0.2.
**Is it the correct approach here?**

```
#Parameters#

pS=0.85 #survival rate Standard vaccine
pT=seq(0.7,0.9,by=0.05) #survival rate Test vaccine range for power analysis

n=seq(8,50)#Number of animals
simu=5000 #number of experiment tried
thresh=0.2 #max acceptable difference to standard for Non inferiority (NI)

mat=matrix(rep(0,length(pT)*length(n)),ncol=length(pT),nrow=length(n))#stored 
c=0 #col index
r=0 #row index

#Simulations#
for (i in pT){ #loop for the different potential values of the test vaccine survival rate
  c=c+1
  r=0
  for (j in n){ # loop for the power for different nbr of animals
    print(j)
    r=r+1
    live_S=rbinom(simu,j,pS) #simulations from binomial law of survival counts in standard vaccine group 
    live_T=rbinom(simu,j,i) #simulations of survival counts in test vaccine group
    temp=c()
    for(k in 1:simu){ #loop comparing every simulations for a given pT and n
      res=prop.test(c(live_S[k],live_T[k]),c(j,j)) #test proportion
      temp=c(temp,res$conf.int[2]) # get the difference CI upper level
    }
    mat[r,c]=sum(temp<thresh)/simu #save the proportion of simulations that were NI
  }
}
```

[image: power analysis]

### II.Bayesian approach:

Having read multiple posts here and papers, I was wondering if I could adopt a Bayesian approach for this problem (I am completely new to Bayesian statistics). The reason is that I am trying to estimate the probability of the effects more than just a yes/no, in order to give more evidence to push the development of the vaccine(or not depending on the result).
My understanding of the procedure is:

- assume some priors of a Beta distribution B(1,1) on the proportions
  of survivals of the different vaccines,
- get the posterior distributions of pS, pC and pT being beta distributions
- get the posterior distributions of the relevant differences (pS-pT
  and pC-pT)sampling using rbeta
- compute the correct Bayes factors of the different hypothesis such as
  for the NI hypothesis $$ BF=\frac{P(pS-pT<m | data)}{P(pS-pT>=m | data)} $$ with m the margin
  decided to declare NI

**Is it the correct procedure for a NI trial ?**
If this procedure is correct, **what is the approach to estimate the number of animals to use in these cases**?
Similarly to the frequentist approach, should I compute different Bayes factor for different potential pT and number of animals and choose a situation with a high enough Bayes Factor?
**Is there some accepted “high enough” Bayes factor in scientific literature?**

Thanks for your help !